# Add fields and correct indentation for json file (using python or ruby)

Tags: python, ruby, json

I have looked at a number of Stackoverflow questions related to this topic but can't find a solution which I can apply.

I have a database of 1450 restaurants, originally as a csv file, with the information for each restaurant occupying one row.

I converted this to a json file using an online tool, but can't get the customisation I want - which I think can only be achieved with code.

This is the nested pattern I need which requires one additional "location" field below "website" and an "address" field below "longitude":

```
{
    "id": 
    "name": 
    "phone": 
    "email": 
    "website": 
    "location": {
        "latitude": 
        "longitude": 
        "address": {
            "line1": 
            "line2": 
            "line3": 
            "postcode"
            "city": 
            "country":
        }
    }
}
```

A sample of the full raw json data I have now from the csv file looks like this (1450 entries):

```
  {
    "id":"101756",
    "name":"1 Lombard Street",
    "phone":"+44 2079296611",
    "email":"reception@1lombardstreet.com",
    "website":"http://www.1lombardstreet.com/",
    "latitude":"51.5129",
    "longitude":"-0.089",
    "line1":"1 Lombard Street",
    "line2":"",
    "line3":"",
    "postcode":"EC3V 9AA",
    "city":"London",
    "country":"UK"
  },
  {
    "id":"105371",
    "name":"108 Brasserie",
    "phone":"+44 2079693900",
    "email":"enquiries@108marylebonelane.com",
    "website":"http://www.108brasserie.com",
    "latitude":"51.51795",
    "longitude":"-0.15079",
    "line1":"108 Marylebone Lane",
    "line2":"",
    "line3":"",
    "postcode":"W1U 2QE",
    "city":"London",
    "country":"UK"
  },
  {
    "id":"108701",
    "name":"1901 Restaurant",
    "phone":"+44 2076187000",
    "email":"london.restres@andaz.com",
    "website":"http://www.andazdining.com",
    "latitude":"51.51736",
    "longitude":"-0.08123",
    "line1":"Andaz Hotel",
    "line2":"40 Liverpool Street",
    "line3":"",
    "postcode":"EC2M 7QN",
    "city":"London",
    "country":"UK"
  },
```

Is there a way using Ruby or Python to change it to the nested pattern in the first example above? How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write up a template file specifying how the records should look like, with field names and empty strings as their values.

Considering the structure you want the data to be in, the format file will look like :

```
{
  "id":"",
  "name":"", 
  "phone":"",
  "email":"", 
  "website":"", 
  "location": {
    "latitude":"", 
    "longitude":"", 
    "address": {
      "line1":"", 
      "line2":"", 
      "line3":"", 
      "postcode":"",
      "city":"", 
      "country":""
     }
  }
}
```

And then utilize it in the code like this :

```
require 'json'

format = JSON.parse File.read('format.json')
records = JSON.parse File.read('input.json')

def convert(record, format)
  ret = {}
  format.each do |key, value|
    ret[key] = record[key] ? record[key] : convert(record, format[key])
  end
  ret
end

records.map! {|record| convert(record, format) }

File.open('output.json', 'w') do |file|
  file << JSON.generate(records)
end
```

It will convert to the format given in the format file. This solution works for any kind of formats, if it's all about just grouping original fields under a new field or fields. You can simply change the format to another in the format file and the data will be converted to that format without any change to the code.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code to convert the data back to the regular CSV list :

```
data = {
  :id => 1,
    :location => {
      :address => {
        :line1 => 'line1'
      }
    },
  :website => 'site'
}

def deconvert(record)
  ret = {}
  record.each do |key, value|
    if value.is_a? Hash
      ret.merge!( deconvert(value) )
    else
       ret.merge!(key => value)
    end
  end
  ret
end

puts deconvert data
# => {:id=>1, :line1=>"line1", :website=>"site"}
```

Comment: Thanks @limekin but when I run it I get this error: `.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in parse: 757: unexpected token (JSON::ParserError)` Any ideas?

Comment: There should be something wrong with the syntax of the json string you are parsing.

Comment: Is there a sample of the data you are trying to read ?

Comment: The data I'm trying to modify with the required indentations and additions (format) is here (not all data as the whole file is 21,735 lines: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/b59e72ad5200006fc1e4

Comment: Yeah okay. From what I know, the one you linked should be enclosed in `[]` since the records make an array. If it isn't, it will show the parse error.

Comment: If you are sure that the whole json data string isn't enclosed in `[]`, then you can try to parse it with : `JSON.parse "[#{File.read('input.json')}]"`.

Comment: thanks v. much @limekin, this appears to be working and nested correctly but outputs as block text. This should be fine for my purposes but is not displayed "pretty" with line breaks to make more human-readable. I will research whether there is some form of pretty method for json module. I recall reading elsewhere that something like this exists. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Yeah there is a method like that : `JSON.pretty_generate`, use it instead of just `JSON.generate` and I think it will look fine for reading then.

Comment: @limkin, this was v. useful for me, but can you break down the code step by step - I now need to do what you did in reverse (ie. no indentation) so a segment of the data can be converted back to CSV - do you know how this can be done? Thanks!

Comment: I also needed to take out the quote marks (as strings) for lat/long and phone with regex. Your code doesn't appear to work when these values don't have quote marks around them.

Comment: Converting back should be simpler, all you have to do is filter out the key, value pairs in the hash where a pairs value is not a hash. But you will have to do that for nested hashes. I will update the answer with code to convert back the data. I didn't really understand the case you said in the second comment, but yeah the code depends on empty strings for values in the format.

Comment: Thanks @limekin, I did the csv conversion bit already, but how do I run your original conversion code if the lat/long fields are not in strings? The ruby just will not run this way.

Comment: You mean in the input data ?

Comment: yes that's right @limekin, I just added " marks manually in the end (then used regex to take them away), so don't worry too much. Just curious why the script only works with them / how can I modify it in future, or which documentation I should read to understand more. (I usually find Ruby 2.1 docs v. hard to understand at this point in my code career)

Comment: But I think there can't be a problem with that. I mean if the input data contains `"latitude": 51.5`, the code should still be able to parse it fine. Or did I not get your concern ?

Comment: sorry for late reply limekin, yes you understood me, it only works with "51.5", but I did that manually, then used regex to change it back (api only takes it as integer not string). So got job done :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to simply iterate over your data, and nest the keys you need

```
data.each do |entry|
  entry[:location] = {}
  entry[:location][:latitude] = entry[:latitude]
  entry[:location][:longitude] = entry[:longitude]
  entry[:location][:address] = {}
  entry[:location][:address][:line1] = entry[:line1]
  ...
  entry.delete(:latitude)
  entry.delete(:longitude)
  ...
end
```

Depending on how you initialy parse your data, each key can be a symbol (`:location`) or a string (`'location'`), and you should call them how they are (example assumes symbols).

Comment: Thanks @piotr. Is this ruby or python? I'm trying to do it in ruby using your solution. This is what I have right now: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/67dd6e809e5c0245a266 But I'm getting `json_script2.rb:5:in each: not opened for reading (IOError)` I think I need another line to "parse" the json after opening the file..Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you need `JSON.parse`, like this: `hash = JSON.parse(myfile)`, then `hash.each ...`. At the end `hash` will be formatted.

Comment: Thanks @piotr, I tried that and now I get this error: `.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in initialize: no implicit conversion of File into String (TypeError)
 from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in new
 from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in parse
 from json_script2.rb:4:in <main>`

Comment: [Here](https://hackhands.com/ruby-read-json-file-hash/)'s how to read a file to json